# how to use an Axios interceptor with Next-Auth

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, react-query, next-auth

I am converting my `CRA` app to `Nextjs` and running into some issues with my `Axios` interceptor pattern.

It works, but I am forced to create and pass an `Axios` instance to every api call.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is what I have now:

`Profile.js`:

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

function Profile(props) {
    const { data: session } = useSession()
    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    useEffect(()=> {
      const proc= async ()=> {
        const user = await getUser(session?.user?.userId)
        setUser(user)
      }
      proc()
    },[])
    
    return <div> Hello {user.userName}<div>
}
```

`getUser.js`:

```
export default async function getUser(userId) {
    const axiosInstance = useAxios()
    const url = apiBase + `/user/${userId}`
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.get(url)
    return data
}
```

`useAxios.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

const getInstance = (token) => {
    const axiosApiInstance = axios.create()

    axiosApiInstance.interceptors.request.use(
        (config) => {
            if (token && !config.url.includes('authenticate')) {
                config.headers.common = {
                    Authorization: `${token}`
                }
            }
            return config
        },
        (error) => {
            Promise.reject(error)
        }
    )

    return axiosApiInstance
}

export default function useAxios() {
    const session = useSession()
    const token = session?.data?.token?.accessToken
    return getInstance(token)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone else has this problem, this was how i solved it (using getSession):

credit to:
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3550#discussioncomment-1993281

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react'

const ApiClient = () => {
    const instance = axios.create()
    instance.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
        const session = await getSession()

        if (session) {
            request.headers.common = {
                Authorization: `${session.token.accessToken}`
            }
        }
        return request
    })

    instance.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
            return response
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(`error`, error)
        }
    )

    return instance
}

export default ApiClient()
```

Comment: It does not look good because it issues session API request on every axios request.

Comment: Agree. This solution sends dozens of the same requests.

Comment: i ended up abandoning converting to nextjs because I was unhappy with this. But I am gearing up to try it again since I've learned a lot since this. Thinking about trying with-iron-session instead

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a neat way on including user extended details to session object

```
// /api/[...nextauth].ts
 ...
 callbacks: {
        session({ session, user, token }) {
            // fetch user profile here. you could utilize contents of token and user
            const profile = getUser(user.userId)

            // once done above, you can now attach profile to session object
            session.profile = profile;

            return session;
        }
    },
```

The you could utilize it as:

```
const { data: session } = useSession()

// Should display profile details not included in session.user
console.log(session.profile)
```

Answer (score -2):

I know one way to do this is to use

```
const session = await getSession()
```

Is there any other way to go about it without using await getSession() because what this does is that it makes a network request to get your session every time your Axios request runs?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33070186)