# Nextjs: how to append jwt token to headers of every API call

Tags: authentication, next.js, axios, jwt

I'm trying to port over my `CRA` app to `NextJs` , but there is ONE thing that is stopping me:

**I would have to append auth token header to EVERY single one of my hundreds of API calls.**

My auth flow is very simple, I call `/authenticate` with username and password to our Express server API and it returns a JWT token. I need to then pass that token with all of the successive API calls in the header.

I need a way to append it in a middleware or something so I dont have to manually add it to every api call.

In my CRA app i used `axios` interceptors for this.

Here is my setup:
`NextJs 13` (using `pages` though, not `/app dir`)

`Iron-Session` version 6

`axios` latest

I tried this in my `middleware.ts`:

```
import { getIronSession } from 'iron-session'
import { sessionOptions } from './lib/session'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
    const res = NextResponse.next()
    const session = await getIronSession(request, res, sessionOptions)
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
    requestHeaders.set('x-hello-from-middleware1', 'hello')
    requestHeaders.set('Authorization', session.user?.jwt || '')

    // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
    const response = NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            // New request headers
            headers: requestHeaders
        }
    })

    // Set a new response header `x-hello-from-middleware2`
    response.headers.set('x-hello-from-middleware2', 'hello')
    return response
}
```

But this gives me this error:

```
error - (middleware)/node_modules/@peculiar/webcrypto/build/webcrypto.es.js (9:0) @ new SubtleCrypto
error - The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module.
```

I've also tried some other random ideas I found on the internet. But i can't get it to work. I've also tried using `Next-Auth` but was unable to get a good solution with that as well (here's my last attempt [how to use an Axios interceptor with Next-Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195813/how-to-use-an-axios-interceptor-with-next-auth/74076287#74076287) )

So is every person using Next manually appending auth token to every single one of their API calls? Am i the only person who needs to do this?  This is my second attempt to convert my CRA to next and auth is blocking me, again. I am not married to iron-session or using middleware.ts , any help appreciated.

Comment: Probably you have resolved the issue by now. But i think meaby you should retrieve the JWT from a cookie instead. Meaby?

Comment: I have a similar issue, I want to switch the middleware runtime to NodeJS (That would fix your issue too). But I can't seem to find any solution. `config = { runtime: 'nodejs' }` is ignored locally, and setting it at top level is ignored too.